# Задание "Can you get the loop?" на Codewars

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Не могу понять, почему мой код не принимает Codewars, хотя я проверял решение у себя на компьютере, в CLion, и всё работает правильно.

[Вот](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52a89c2ea8ddc5547a000863/cpp) само задание в Codewars.

Вот мой вариант решения (+ дописал сам класс Node, но это чисто для того, чтобы проверить работу функции getLoopSize в CLion - в Codewars в решении сам класс я не вставлял):

```
#include <vector>
// Для std::binary_search.
#include <algorithm>
// Для тестов ниже.
#include <iostream>

class Node
{
public:
    Node* nextNode = nullptr;
    Node* getNext() { return nextNode; }
    void setNext(Node* node) { nextNode = node; }
};

int getLoopSize(Node* startNode)
{
    // Определяем, с какого элемента начинается цикл.
    std::vector<Node*> nodes_ptr { startNode };
    do
    {
      startNode = startNode->getNext();
      bool isAlreadyThere = std::binary_search(nodes_ptr.begin(), nodes_ptr.end(), startNode);
      if (isAlreadyThere) { break; }
      else { nodes_ptr.push_back(startNode); }
    } while (true);

    // Определяем индекс повторяющегося элемента.
    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes_ptr.size(); ++i)
    {
      if (nodes_ptr[i] == startNode) { index = i; break; }
    }   

    // Выводим длину цикла.
    return nodes_ptr.size() - index;
}
```

Вот один из тестов, всё выполняется так, как и было задумано:

```
int main()
{
    Node n1, n2, n3, n4;

    n1.setNext(&n2);
    n2.setNext(&n3);
    n3.setNext(&n4);
    n4.setNext(&n2);

    // Выводит 3, как и задумано (у системы узлов tail = 1, loop = 3).
    std::cout << getLoopSize(&n1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Тот же самый тест, но на Codewars, выдаёт мне следующее сообщение:

```
Incorrect answer for 4 nodes: tail of 1 node, and a loop of 3 nodes  
Expected: equal to 3  
Actual: 12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не с той стороны подходите к решению задачи.

Эта задача решается с помощью двух указателей; один на каждом шаге переходит на один узел вперед, второй — на два. Далее, рано или поздно, но за O(N) :), они совпадут — в этот момент вы находитесь уже в цикле, после чего найти его длину — задача тривиальная.

Ваш метод дает O(N^2), так как на каждом шаге требует просмотра всех пройденных узлов.

Answer (score 1):

`std::binary_search` работает только с отсортированными данными (не говоря уже о том что сложность поиска у него логарифмическая). Посему использовать надо `std::find` (у него к слову сложность линейная):

```
auto it = std::find(nodes_ptr.begin(), nodes_ptr.end(), startNode);
bool isAlreadyThere = it!=nodes_ptr.end();
```